# вызов события по таймеру

Tags: c#

Как в c sharp вызвать метод по таймеру?

```
TimerCallback tm = new TimerCallback(doIt());
System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(tm, 0, 0, 3600000);
```

При таком варианте ругается на метод и требует имя метода.

```
public void doIt()
        {
```

Comment: Потому что нужно указывать без скобочек.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TimerCallback tm = new TimerCallback(doIt);
```

ну или сразу

```
System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(doIt, 0, 0, 3600000);
```

Для правильной сигнатуры функции

```
void doIt(object ob) 
{
    ....
}
```